# Submit form only if file is selected

Tags: jquery, file, events, submit

Hey there in my jquery i am checking "on submit", if file is selected or not:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form").submit(function(){
    var fileName = $("#picture-field").val();

    if(fileName) { // returns true if the string is not empty
        alert(fileName + " was selected");
    } else { // no file was selected
        alert("no file selected");
    }
  });
});
```

If no file is selected, it displays: "no file selected", but then the form is sbumitted.

But i want that the form can only be submitted if a file is selected.

If no file selected and the user presses "submit", e.g. display: "please select file".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

only add `return false`  after the `alert()`, This will cancel the submit.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form").submit(function(){
    var fileName = $("#picture-field").val();

    if(fileName) { // returns true if the string is not empty
        alert(fileName + " was selected");
    } else { // no file was selected
        alert("no file selected");
        return false; //<---- Add this line.
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

simply add return false, when you don't want to submit form. This will stop click event propagation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form").submit(function(){
    var fileName = $("#picture-field").val();

    if(fileName) { // returns true if the string is not empty
        alert(fileName + " was selected");
    } else { // no file was selected
        alert("no file selected");
        return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form").submit(function(){
    var fileName = $("#picture-field").val();

    if(fileName) { 
       alert(fileName + " was selected");
    } else { // no file was selected
       alert("no file selected");
       return false; 
    }
 });
});
```

simply use return false